# What information can I use to determine which answers need improving in order to lift an answer ban?

Tags: discussion, support, post-ban

Looking over my answer history from my profile page, I see multiple answers, but none with a negative score that would lead me to believe it is inferior (and which I can improve).

What information can I use to deduce which answer(s) I need to improve? [The answer bans Help Center page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans) gives me information on what I need to do, however, it provides no useful information in how to detect which answers need improving.

[image: My profile page, with the questions, answers, reputation, and tags section visible; there are four total answers, three of which have a score of 0, one has a score of 1]

Comment: if the post exists, and *can* be improved to state where it will be useful to future users, it is a good candidate for improvement that can help you get out of the ban. Positively scored, negatively scored, 0 score, closed, it doesn't matter. All that matters is that you gain upvotes and/or reduce downvotes.

Comment: You’ll need a mod to provide the links to your deleted answers, to see if you could salvage any of those. If the parent question itself was deleted, not much you could do.

Comment: Just in case you have deleted answers, keep in mind that they will also taken into account.

Comment: i would focus on the posts that have received the most views, as views are what drive votes. You'll never gain upvotes on an answer that's posted to a question getting no new views. (though... improving the question your answer is on can certainly fix this)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I think your approach may have ramifications that could lead to some users needing to wait indefinitely for those upvotes to occur. I'm hoping to avoid that. To give you an idea, I have been unable to post for over a year now, and, no change to upvote or downvote status on any of my posts. While the suggestion that improvement to them could change this, what grounds do you have to believe that?

Comment: @RobertLongson Interesting. I have no memory of deleting any posts, however there are plenty with 0 votes. What about the maximum time between answers?

Comment: @Robert this is about an answer ban, not a question ban. There is no “six month shot” for a-bans.

Comment: There are no quick fixes. The hole has been dug already. You can only work on your existing answers (and maybe even try to improve any question you answered), and hope they attract attention and upvotes.

Comment: You have the following 4 deleted answers: [A1](//stackoverflow.com/a/60662802), [A2](//stackoverflow.com/a/60105110), [A3](//stackoverflow.com/a/60104297), and [A4](//stackoverflow.com/a/57315479).

Comment: @yivi two things: 
1. `The hole has been dug already` - part of this was meant to be a discussion. It sounds like you can see a hole. Would you mind sharing that with me? Thats exactly why I created this question post. If not maybe your kicking against the developers of stackoverflow.

2. I don't remember seeing a disclaimer saying that stackoverflow doesn't want to improve existing questions with answers. In fact, that seems like the general idea.

Comment: @yivi an answer to a question with 26 other answers. People will have to dig to find it.

Comment: “The hole” = your current situation. The answer ban that results from your overall answer score.

Comment: @yivi thanks for clarifying. It sounded like you were imputing some guilt in me based off my answers. My mistake.

Comment: @Makyen Ah i see what probably caused it. That A4 had -4 votes. Which is probably why i removed it. At the time i was just getting into stack overflow. But hey, at least having deleted it shows that I try my best to moderate myself. Maybe just for new users it would make sense to be a little bit more flexible.

Comment: I do note, however, that the system says that you are not *currently* banned from answering questions, but that you were quite recently blocked. that change is most likely the result of the upvote you received about 50 minutes ago on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59976885/how-would-i-consolidate-spring-localization-messages-properties-bundle-to-anothe/60556155#60556155).

Comment: @janst [A4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57315479) was deleted by a moderator, not yourself. While there are some differences as to how the system handles that (e.g. non-moderators can't undelete it), I'm mostly pointing it out due to a desire for accuracy (which might be a bit overboard).

Comment: @Makyen can you make an answer including how I can find those deleted posts and then a suggestion including how you would edit/change them to avoid/escape a ban? I suppose that random comment that I made as an answer to a question really isn't helpful. But what should a new user do to get unbanned in that scenario?

Comment: @janst That info is *largely* covered in the [existing FAQ on this topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/), but the means of finding your own deleted posts that are old enough to age out of the "recently deleted" link at the bottom of [your profile answers page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=answers) isn't straightforward, and could be greatly improved.

Comment: @Makyen Doesn't a new user need 50 rep to comment? In which case, wanting to help, their only recourse would be to make an answer? I don't want to get into the weeds of another discussion though.

Comment: @janst As is covered in many meta posts, the solution of abusing the answer box to post a request for clarification is not an acceptable solution. The fact that the system limits users to not commenting, except on their own posts, until they have >= 50 reputation is expected to be respected, not circumvented by abusing another feature.

Comment: It would be, so you have to resist the urge to help unless you know it will have a positive impact. The rep requirement is almost certainly because of the <expletive deleted>heads that would otherwise use SO as their own personal spam server.

Comment: @user4581301 I see, I guess it can't be helped then. Which means, people who do exactly what I did will no longer be able to make a thread like this and get unbanned. (duplicate) So as great as SO is, i think it really needs a new feature which gives new guys a chance. Any dedicated spammer would easily manipulate the systems trust factor by just upvoting their other account's questions/answers. So it makes sense to me to just deter the undedicated spammers, and be more kind to the new users.

Comment: My recommendation is pick and choose those first few questions. Pick questions that have concrete, exact answers where you know the exact answer. Pick recent questions because they get eyes a lot faster, at least for the first few hours. Don't add a new answer to a n old question that already has good answers. You may have a better answer, but save it for later because it's unlikely that anyone will see that answer for a few days. No point to coming back years later to find out the "answer that got you banned" was upvoted to War and Peace-status two days later.

Comment: Answer carefully and cover the immediate bases, but don't clutter the answer with too many extra details. If an answer requires a bunch of extra details to be answered correctly, it's probably too broad and should be closed instead. That's fuzzy so you'll have to make the call on a case-by-case basis. Once you have a few well received questions you can stop treating SO like a game where you have to maximize the point intake, but if you're risking a ban, you need to be careful. I have no idea if I came close to a ban with my early turds, but I don't recall getting a warning.

Comment: Unrelated, I'm not sure there are dedicated spammers. The point of spamming is to maximize value for investment, so any required effort seems to be an effective deterrent. Same reason why spammers use well-known cannards like the Nigerian prince: people who detect such a pathetically stupid attempt as a scam select themselves out a for you and you don't have to waste any effort trying to rope them in. You only get callbacks from the desperate, confused, stupid, or excessively greedy. People you won't have to work very hard to separate from their money.

Comment: @user4581301 very true. I would argue the same for users in my predicament on SO. Not many people are willing to go through the effort to be un-banned by editing other SO answers which they have no interest in just to get points.

Comment: Another couple of points:  1) Avoid posting answers to question asked a long time ago that already have lots of answers.  You probably are not going to add anything that has not already been said already.  (Read >>all<< of the other answers ... before adding yet another.)  Some people will downvote late answers that don't add anything new.  Simply because it then makes them candidates for deletion.

Comment: 2) If your answer is simply relating your opinion and/or your experiences, consider that such answers tend not to be helpful.  Good answers are based on verifiable objective facts, not opinions and anecdotal evidence.

Comment: Of course, this advice doesn't help is you have already written answers like this.  Neither of those issues are easily remediable ... after the fact.

Answer (score 3):

Nominally, only *positively* scored answers will positively get you out of the hole.

However, I did look at your answers and I didn't see anything particularly *wrong* with them.  They may just be overlooked in the deluge of other answers for questions in those tags.

Comment: There's usually a deadweight of more highly downvoted and then deleted ones dragging things down.

Comment: @RobertLongson:  *Usually*, yes, but...benefit of the doubt?  Maybe I'm feeling benevolent today.

Comment: After getting a single upvote by some kind individual, I was able to post my answer that was previously blocked. While thats great news. It feels a little too strict of an algorithm if stackoverflow wants to encourage new users.

Comment: @janst:  This is partly why I didn't want to jump to conclusions about this being the typical circumstance we see which is, someone jumps on Meta to complain about a ban and then they have like 20 downvoted questions.  If *one* upvoted answer got you out of the hole, then you were caught in a unique edge case - I think you're OK.

Comment: It's a catch 22, @janst. Stack overflow doesn't want answers. It wants *good* answers, and *good* is decided by the users helped by the answer and (usually in an initial burst after posting) other readers who think the answer should be helpful.

Comment: @janst - It’s supposed to be strict. If you submit high quality answers that are not deleted and are not downvoted then you move away from the answer ban threshold. Answer bans happen after a continued pattern of submitting low quality answers. Avoid using answers as a way to submit a long comment to take part in a discussion. I agree with a previous comment, you submitted a extremely low quality answer to a question that absolutely didn’t need another low quality answer